# How to add an uploaded file to a list of already uploaded files in Vue?

Tags: file-upload, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I currently have a file uploader that accepts a single CSV file. Then with axios I POST such file to the server and everything works just fine. What I'm not being able to achieve is being able to upload another CSV that will get added to the list of CSVs uploaded. I'm not talking about uploading various files at once, I'm taking about uploading different files at different points in time.

This is the method that is used to select a CSV file in the .vue file.

```
 staticCampaignCSVSelected: function (file) {
  console.log('campaign-detail.vue#staticCampaignCSVSelected', file)
  let vc = this
  vc.selectedHeuristicId = -1
  Campaign.uploadStaticCSV(vc.campaign, file[0])
  .then(
    function (data) {
      alert('CSV cargado con exito')
    }
  )
  .catch(
    function (err, data) {
      console.log("campaign-detail#staticCampaignCSVSelected - catch", err.response)
      alert(err.response.data.error)
    }
  )
},
```

This is the function that I have in some other JS file to POST to the API:

```
function uploadStaticCSV (campaign, csv) {
  console.log('Campaign#uploadStaticCSV', campaign, csv)


  //long list of assertions

  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('csv', csv)

  return axios.post(API.campaignUploadStaticCSV(campaign.id), formData)
}
```

And this is the function I have in my endpoints.js file:

```
campaignUploadStaticCSV: function (id) { return this.campaign(id) + '' + '/csv' },
```

I haven't found a way to properly pass a`[file]` array as a parameter to the functions, which is what I believe I need to somehow do.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i  understood  your question you need a way to pass a file from browser interface to your staticCampaignCSVSelected(file) method. If so why not to use an input model or a simple event or a watcher. E.g.

```
<input type="file" @input="staticCampaignCSVSelected($event.target.files[0])" />
```

But also i see a mistake in your code. You should append .then().catch() callbacks to axios.post() itself but not to Campaign.uploadStaticCSV() method.

And

```
return axios.post()
```

will not return a server response. You have to handle it in

```
axios.post().then(response => {})
```

callback

Comment: Hey thanks for answer. The watcher would work absolutely fine, but what I need is a way to upload multiple files. This just allows to upload a single file. 

On the other hand `return axios.post()` indeed returns a server response. Not exactly sure why, but it's working.

Comment: @EstebanVargas for multiple files upload you can use `<input type="file" multiple @input="staticCampaignCSVSelected($event.target.files)" />`